# How can a comment box like this be achieved?

Tags: ios

I'm not sure whether this is something that's ok to ask here but worth a try. Does anybody have any insight into how a comment box like this can be achieved. I don't mean style wise I just mean the text field and the button at the bottom of the page and then when you click on the textfield it moves up with the keyboard rather than get the keyboard appear over it.

I thought a custom UITabBar but wasn't sure if you can add textfield elements to it.

Here is the example:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

A `tableFooterView`, probably just containing some subviews. Animate the table view frame when the keyboard shows / hides and the footer will automatically move (as it's always at the bottom of the table view).

If the table view can be empty and you always want the comment box at the bottom then a separate view and constraints for the layout could be better. As the keyboard changes you then animate a constraint constant to move the views & resize.

Comment: Could you elaborate on option 2 as I think that better fits my purpose.